# SVG button cursor not visible

Tags: wordpress, svg, button, cursor

I have these custom svg icons that I use inside a lightbox to go back and forth. I think I set everything up correctly: the url is correct, the size too, but they still don't show up.

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
#next-button {
cursor: url('http://leonardodevito.local/wp-content/themes/leonardo_devito/img/vector_58.svg'), default !important;
height: 100vh;
}
#previous-button {
cursor: url('http://leonardodevito.local/wp-content/themes/leonardo_devito/img/vector_62_copia.svg'), default !important;
height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  width: 100% !important
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Here is the SVG code
Help!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.5.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0) -->
<svg width="73" height="144" version="1.1" id="Level_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 73 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 73 144;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M1,143l71-71L1,1"/>
</svg>
```

I have these custom svg icons that I use inside a lightbox to go back and forth. I think I set everything up correctly: the url is correct, the size too, but they still don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

The size of images used as cursors cannot exceed 128x128: [Icon size limits | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#icon_size_limits). So, here I have cut down the size:

Previous:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="64" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 49 1 L 1 50 L 49 99"/>
</svg>
```

Next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="64" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 1 1 L 50 49 L 1 99"/>
</svg>
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#next-button {
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MCAxMDAiPgo8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBkPSJNIDEgMSBMIDUwIDQ5IEwgMSA5OSIvPgo8L3N2Zz4KCgo='), default !important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
}

#previous-button {
  cursor: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MCAxMDAiPgo8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBkPSJNIDQ5IDEgTCAxIDUwIEwgNDkgOTkiLz4KPC9zdmc+CgoK'), default !important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="previous-button"></div>
<div id="next-button"></div>
```